# 'modificar' o actualizar objeto mapeado JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Estamos estudiando persistencia en una base de datos relacional(MySQL) con Java, las capas de JPA...
Bien, tenemos un proyecto que simula una tienda(típico) en la cual, se logea un usuario, se comprueba que esté en la base de datos y tal, lo típico.

Cuando el usuario 'compra' algo, se hace un insert en una tabla, que nos sirve a modo de carrito de la compra.
Cuando queremos listar lo que el usuario lleva añadido, nos muestra todo lo que haya en la tabla añadido por ese usuario hasta el momento de ejecutar la aplicación, nada de lo que haya hecho mientras la está usando logeado.
Si recargamos la aplicación y listamos, ya sí que nos sale los últimos cambios realizados.

Hemos creado el Objeto usuario de nuevo, a ver si hacía un nuevo mapeo actualizado al crear el objeto, pero tampoco funciona. Entonces, he llegado a la conclusión de que el mapeo se realiza al ejecutar la aplicación y no se puede modificar 'en tiempo real'.

Estoy en lo cierto que esta tecnología no funciona así, o ¿estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Buenas Rafa, el objeto persona que creaste con los datos en una solicitud "x" tenía tal datos, después de insertar en la tabla compras, el objeto sigue teniendo los mismos datos porque no lo has ido actualizando.
Sería más fácil si pusieras algo de código.
Mysql es la base de datos, phpmyAdmin es el entorno gráfico.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin es un cliente para trabajar con MySQL

Comment: @Shaz es que no lo es. Simplemente es un software para acceder a MySQL

Comment: @JDev si revisas las ediciones de la pregunta, entenderás por qué lo digo. Te invito a revisar todas las preguntas que tienen la etiqueta phpmyadmin y verás a lo que me refiero.

Comment: @Rafa lo que tienes que hacer es hacer un update de la tabla donde guardas las compras del usuario si añades a la pregunta código puede ayudarte

Comment: @RaulCacacho Al final lo arreglé tocando algo del Netbeans, cambié el Shared Caché Mode que estaba desactivado por activado y empezó a funcionar como debía. Nuestra profesora decía que no hacía falta hacer un update a la lista, ya que el objeto está relacionado directamente con la base de datos y se debía actualizar solo...
La cuentión es que ahora hemos empezado a hacer otra cosa y estoy en el mismo dilema...

Comment: @Rafa Solo quieres actualizar la lista en memoria lo puedes hacer lista.add(tuobjeto);